# Can we sort on multi column using QTableWidget? Or do I have to subclass from QTableView?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtableview, qtablewidget

I am in my way of developing a custom QTableWidget widget. All are progressing well..until I reach into multi column sorting. Can we do this in QTableWidget? Or do I have to subclass from QTableView and have to rewrite my custom widget?

I am looking at [this code actually](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_sort_the_items_in_a_qtablewidget_on_multiple_columns), but having saw (and test) this line of code:

```
 for (int i=sortOrder.size() - 1; i>=0; --i) {
            sortItems(sortOrder.at(i).column, sortOrder.at(i).ascending ? Qt::AscendingOrder : Qt::DescendingOrder);
```

I realize that it won't work. After you sort using `sortItems` and rerun it in the other columns, what you get is the sorting of that last column.

Any suggestion?
I would love to keep using QTableWidget by the way ;)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to subclass the `QTableWidget` in order to make it sortable. To enable sorting you have to use `QTableView::setSortingEnabled()` function that will turn on the built in sorting capabilities. For example:

```
tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

Comment: It will work only for single column sorting. For multiple column, It only provide, `sortByColumn(column)` or `sortItems(column, sort_order)`. I was expecting that the `sortItems()` can be use to sort multi columns, but it didn't

Comment: @swdev, what do you mean saying "sort multi columns"? I am not aware of such capability. The only way I can sort is clicking on the header view and sort the **corresponding column**. Besides, `QTreeWidget::sortItems()` accepts a column number, and not the list of columns as the first argument.

Comment: Yes, indeed it didn't support it. I guess I will  be forced to rework my current custom widget to subclass into QTableView.. gosh.. I hope it didn't as bad as I think it is.. :) http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/1349